# socket.io dynamic send and revice messages

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

How can i send message to dynamic room, and when server receive that message, to send that message to same room for other members?

`table_id` is room, and it will be set dynamically..

Client:

```
var table_id = 1; // example, python will give this value

var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    socket.emit('join', "table_"+table_id);
});

socket.on("table_"+table_id, function(data) {
   console.log('New data:', data);
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    // send message to that room
});
```

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('join', function(table) {
    console.log('joined to table '+table);
    socket.join(table);
  });

  // when receive message from particular room, send it back to others in same room

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need namespaces, not rooms.
You may broadcast events in one namespace for all members in this room.

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

But if you want to do classic chat messages, just broadcast message to entire room:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

For example:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('join', function(table) {
        console.log('joined to table '+table);
        socket._room = table
        socket.join(table);
    });
    // when receive message from particular room, send it back to others in same room
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        io.to(socket._room).emit('some event',message);
    });
});
```

And client side:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    // send message to that room
    socket.emit('message', $('.message').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine.. but why should i use namespace here, with dynamic room? and can you give me example with namespace?

Comment: There is a sample, not so good as with rooms, but it is for another cases: https://gist.github.com/ramainen/3c738641fc7fbe3ca6fc

Comment: So, namespaces for cases, where your table* does different things. For example, table_messages and table_tasks.

Comment: And last thing: now socket.io don't delete rooms after last user disconnected, there is a bug. In large projects you mabe must delete rooms manually because memory issues.

Comment: How can i delete rooms when noone is in?